# Fastest way to read throw XSLX rows in any language

Tags: excel, xlsx

I need to get last X number of completely filled (pre-defined cols) rows in XSLX file. "Completely filled row" meaning all predefined columns have values, which doesn't necessary means last row, as there could be some rows in the end with incomplete data set. I think it leaves me with option to iterate through all rows until I find the last one that fits my req't. I'm talking about 10s of thousands of rows file though.

But it looks like most libraries, though, do some scanning of provided file before you can do anything with it, to provide convenience methods like "last row", "last col", etc..

I wonder if someone maybe already did something similar and already did some performance testing, and can suggest a fast library in any language (I just need to get X last rows (based on one col values)), and save to DB). I'm currently doing it in Perl, but it takes ~2.5 minutes to process some of the files I get..

Linux, no MS Office dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **.net core** you can use **DocumentFormat.OpenXml** [(Nuget link)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). It should be possible to read your files fast with this lib. If it's a really large file you could use the SAX-approach to read the  file instead of loading the whole DOM into memory [Exemple 
 on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet)

Comment: thanks! I just did a simple test, SAX approach. and it goes pretty fast, not sure how much faster it can get. I'll need some more tests. really appreciate the suggestion